# Image of the intertwining operator for GL(2) is $K$-invariant at the "pole" $s=1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, langlands-conjectures, eisenstein-series

I am taking a look at the residues of Eisenstein series and have a question about a local computation.  Let $k$ be a local field, $G = \operatorname{GL}_2(k)$, and $P$ (resp. $K$) the standard parabolic (resp. maximal) compact subgroup of $G$.  Let $I(s)$ be the induced representation consisting of all continuous functions $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb C$ satisfying

$$f( \begin{matrix} t_1 & x 
\\ 0 & t_2 
\end{matrix}g) = |t_1t_2^{-1}|^{(s+1)/2}f(g)$$

for all $g \in G, 0 \neq t_i, x \in \mathbb R$.  The intertwining operator $M(s): I(s) \rightarrow I(-s)$ is defined formally by

$$M(s)f(g) = \int\limits_k f(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} g) dx$$

It converges (I think) for $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 0$, but admits a meromorphic continuation to all $s$ with a pole at $s=0$.

It seems to be the case that when $k = \mathbb R$, $M(1)$ takes $I(1)$ into $I(-1)^K$, which is to say $M(1)f(gk) = M(1)f(g)$ for all $g \in G, k \in K$ (on math.stackexchange I wrote an answer working this out over $\mathbb R$).  This is interesting, because $s=1$ is a pole of the global intertwining operator, given by tensoring the local operators $M(s)$ together.  Does $M(1)$ always map $I(1)$ into $I(-1)^K$, when $k$ is *any* local field?

Answer (score 2):

The representations $M(1)$ and $M(-1)$ both have length $2$. The first one has the Steinberg representation ${\rm St}$ as subrepresentation and the trivial representation $\mathbf 1$ as quotient. The second has the trivial representation as subrepresentation and the Steinberg representation as quotient. From this any non-zero intertwining operator from $M(1)$ to $M(-1)$ must map $M(1)$ to ${\mathbf 1}=M(-1)^K$.